# handle fastapi endpoint multiple requests parallelly python

Tags: python, fastapi

I have a fastapi enpoint like '@app.get("/data/")' which gets the data from database based on parameters passed. I would like to handle multiple requests to this endpoint asynchronously or parallelly.

sample fast api endpoint:

```
cluster = Cluster(nodes)
session = cluster.connect()
@app.get("/data/{user}")
async def getusername(user:str):

query = "SELECT * from testbd WHERE user={}".format(user)

rows = session.execute(query)
data = []
for row in rows:
    data.append(row)
return JSONResponse(content=jsonable_encoder(data), status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

could you suggest what would be the best way to handle mutiple requests parallelly.

Comment: If you're not using async compatible libraries (such as when making a database query), don't define your controller endpoints as async compatible - async is not the same as running something in parallell. Instead, create multiple workers when running your application, and define the endpoints without async.

Answer (score 1):

Your endpoint fully blocks on the `session.execute` call. If you want concurrency with async, you need to make sure *all* I/O calls are done asynchronously.

This means you *must* use the [asyncio extension](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/asyncio.html) for SqlAlchemy.

So you want something like the following:

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import async_sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine

engine = create_async_engine("your_connection_string")
async_session = async_sessionmaker(engine)

@app.get("/data/{user}")
async def get_user_name(user: str):
    query = build_your_query()
    async with async_session() as session:
        rows = await session.execute(query)


    # generate your response
```

Now, in addition to this, never ever use string formatting to build your query. This is a SQL Injection attack waiting to happen. Since you are using SQLAlchemy already, either use its Core or ORM framework to build queries safely.

Comment: in your code session will be created per each request.
what is the best way to create db session, is it good to create a session per each request.

Comment: should I create ''session = cluster.connect()'' inside my get_user_name method

Comment: also I am connecting to Cassandra, I am not sure I can use sqlalchemy